# PostgreSQL: Switching schema name in a loop

Tags: postgresql, schema, multi-tenant

I am trying to switch the schema name dynamically to do some data manipulation.

I am running the following.

```
DO $$
DECLARE schema_name TEXT;
BEGIN
FOR schema_name in
        select "name" from public.tenants
    Loop
        RAISE NOTICE 'The current schema is %', schema_name;
        INSERT INTO schema_name.campuses (select * from public.campuses where code = schema_name);
    End Loop;
END $$;
```

However I am presented with the following

> NOTICE:  The current schema is NTU
>
> ERROR:  relation "schema_name.campuses" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT
> INTO schema_name.campuses (select * from public.campu...
> ^ QUERY:  INSERT INTO schema_name.campuses (select * from public.campuses where code = schema_name) CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at SQL statement SQL state: 42P01

I have tried wrapping the schema_name in "" as well as [].
Is there a solution to this as my googling is not helping me at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you raise a `WARNING` try a `INFO` instead

Additional you need dynamic sql see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

```
DO $$
DECLARE schema_name TEXT;
BEGIN
SET client_min_messages TO INFO;
FOR schema_name in
        select "name" from test.public.tenants
    Loop            
        RAISE info 'The current schema is %', schema_name;
        EXECUTE CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', schema_name , '.campuses (select * from public.campuses where code =  $1);')
   USING  schema_name;
    End Loop;
END $$;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @nbk still getting the following error
ERROR:  relation "schema_name.campuses" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO schema_name.campuses (select * from public.campu...

Comment: I changed my answer, to a prepared statenst

Comment: This is great thank you. It works